# meteor android crosswalk webview login not visible

Tags: android, cordova, meteor

Meteor  crosswalk does reveal the Sign In/Up button when the apk is developed via crosswalk to load an external website. However when the app is built via meteor and the crosswalk CordovaLib used to replace the existing directory then Sign In/Up is not visible.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like there is nothing special about Crosswalk, but rather you compiled your app in a way, it cannot connect to the server.

Comment: simply replacing the CordovaLib with the Crosswalk version fails to build. How about simply placing the Crosswalk CordovaLib in cordova-build-override ?

Comment: i will try your way https://meteor.hackpad.com/Building-Meteor-app-with-Crosswalk-kHKh4DzGxFQ

Comment: build via eclipse seemed to work by just overwriting the CordovaLib ,where ant debug failed

Comment: now the server responds when the app is running,publishing, but the sign in/up button fails to show. now crosswalk is correctly in place for CordovaLib, building without error on eclipse ADK. i will force enable login for a further test

Comment: the crosswalk app made outside of meteor does work. now via eclipse the  app made via meteor "build" does connect however no javascript runs as an auto login was made which fails to run.

Comment: the app without crosswalk made within meteor will not connect and display the Sign in/up buttons. so a test app must be made in incremental fashion to find the point of failure

Comment: yes Microscope does run as an android app made via meteor build so some changes must be made to the 'new' app for it to also run, finally.

Comment: removing and installing "login" packages of Microscope did not allow login to work via the app. Now remove the "npm" packages ?

Answer (score 0):

the "new" app has accounts-password                   1.0.4  Password support for accounts
bootstrap                           1.0.1  Front-end framework from Twitter
email                               1.0.4  Send email messages
iron:router                         1.0.1  Routing specifically designed for Meteor
jquery                              1.0.1  Manipulate the DOM using CSS selectors
meteor-platform                     1.2.0  Include a standard set of Meteor packages in your app
meteorhacks:npm                     1.2.0  Use npm modules with your Meteor App
mrt:accounts-ui-bootstrap-dropdown  0.8.3  Bootstrap styled version of login widgets
npm-container                       1.0.0  Contains all your npm dependencies

however Microscope has
accounts-password            1.0.4  Password support for accounts
audit-argument-checks        1.0.1  Try to detect inadequate input sanitization
ian:accounts-ui-bootstrap-3  1.1.21  Bootstrap-styled accounts-ui with multi-language support.
iron:router                  1.0.1  Routing specifically designed for Meteor
mizzao:bootstrap-3           3.3.0  HTML, CSS, and JS framework for developing responsive, mobile first projects on the web.
sacha:spin                   2.0.4  Simple spinner package for Meteor
standard-app-packages        1.0.3  Moved to meteor-platform
underscore                   1.0.1  Collection of small helpers: _.map, _.each, ...

so clearly the different packages likely make a problem for meteor to package/compile the android app

the "bootstrap" package was the problem, using mizzao:bootstrap-3 solved it.. ugg !